# JPA no persistence found

Tags: java, maven, jpa

first and foremost I don't think this is a duplicate because I checked the folders names and also the persistence name file

I updated the pom to work with maven as well.

```
  <dependencies>
      
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate (JPA Implementation) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.6.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Derby -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>10.15.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
  </dependencies>
```

I still get the persistence not found

[please check image for more context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CIwB.png)

```
<persistence-unit name="Memories" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

Here's the datamaper

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import com.fcul.memoriesdb.domain.Photograph;

import java.util.List;
 
public class PhotographDataMapper {
 
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
 
    public PhotographDataMapper() {
        // Create the EntityManagerFactory
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Memories");
```

Comment: Hey! Please add the error message as text and not as images :)

Comment: Why are you using `org.apache.derby:derby:10.15.2.0` if you've configured `persistence.xml` for connections to a MySQL DB server? I think you should include the dependency to [ConnectorJ](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j) instead.

Comment: In your `persistence.xml`, why are you configuring `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider` as your provider if you plan to use Hibernate? I'm pretty sure you want that to be `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Implementations of JPA specification include:

- Hibernate
- EclipseLink

You imported Hibernate JAR but specified EclipseLink as JPA provider:

```xml
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

Use Hibernate provider instead:

```xml
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

Comment: What do I do if I want to use the eclipseLink as my jpa provider? I don't need Hibernate

Comment: Then in your pom replace org.hibernate:hibernate-core with org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink. See artifact at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/4.0.2

Comment: It still does the same error, I can send you the files if you want to check it out